# Difference between EasyMock.createStrictMock(class<T> x) and EasyMock.createNiceMock(class<T> x)

Tags: java, easymock

In the API doc it is mentioned that in the strictmock order checking is enabled by default while in case of nice mock it is not . I did not get what exactly they meant by "order checking".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you tell a mock to expect a call to `foo()`, then to expect a call to `bar()`, and the actual calls are `bar()` then `foo()`, a strict mock will complain but a nice mock won't. That's what order checking means.

Comment: That's not it though, if bear() is called on the mock, a nice mock will use the un-mocked implementation of bear() and won't complain. A strict mock will

Answer (score 0):

EasyMock.createStrictMock() creates a mock and also takes care of the order of method calls that the mock is going to make in due course of its action.
Consider below example:
[Click here for complete tutorial.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/easymock/index.htm)

```
@Before
   public void setUp(){
      mathApplication = new MathApplication();
      calcService = EasyMock.createStrictMock(CalculatorService.class);
      mathApplication.setCalculatorService(calcService);
   }

   @Test
   public void testAddAndSubtract(){

      //add the behavior to add numbers
      EasyMock.expect(calcService.add(20.0,10.0)).andReturn(30.0);

      //subtract the behavior to subtract numbers
      EasyMock.expect(calcService.subtract(20.0,10.0)).andReturn(10.0);

      //activate the mock
      EasyMock.replay(calcService); 

      //test the subtract functionality
      Assert.assertEquals(mathApplication.subtract(20.0, 10.0),10.0,0);

      //test the add functionality
      Assert.assertEquals(mathApplication.add(20.0, 10.0),30.0,0);

      //verify call to calcService is made or not
      EasyMock.verify(calcService);
   }
```

EasyMock.createNiceMock(): If multiple methods have same functionality, we can create NiceMock object and create only 1 expect(method) and can create multiple assert(method1), assert(method2),...

```
@Before
   public void setUp(){
      mathApplication = new MathApplication();
      calcService = EasyMock.createNiceMock(CalculatorService.class);
      mathApplication.setCalculatorService(calcService);
   }

   @Test
   public void testCalcService(){

      //add the behavior to add numbers
      EasyMock.expect(calcService.add(20.0,10.0)).andReturn(30.0);

      //activate the mock
      EasyMock.replay(calcService); 

      //test the add functionality
      Assert.assertEquals(mathApplication.add(20.0, 10.0),30.0,0);

      //test the subtract functionality
      Assert.assertEquals(mathApplication.subtract(20.0, 10.0),0.0,0);

      //test the multiply functionality
      Assert.assertEquals(mathApplication.divide(20.0, 10.0),0.0,0);        

      //test the divide functionality
      Assert.assertEquals(mathApplication.multiply(20.0, 10.0),0.0,0);

      //verify call to calcService is made or not
      EasyMock.verify(calcService);
   }
```